# Training neural networks in parallel, theoretical framework

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow, neural-network, theano, keras

I'm working with neural networks and currently exploring other ways than my cpu to accelerate the training process. Using Keras with Tensorflow on a GPU machine in AWS I was able to really speed up the process.

**How does this parallelization work in theory?** *(I am not considering cluster parallelization)*

I struggled to find a reference so I ask you for an insight into how it works.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you used a *single* GPU then the speedup is given by the hardware being faster at performing matrix multiplications. There is no parallelization involved besides techniques to efficiently compute the Neural Network operation on a GPU machine.

Comment: Yep, that's the case. 

I apologize for a second question, hope it doesn't bother you: is there something like openMP , shared memory training of neural networks as you know?

Comment: @fabrizioM Speed-ups from GPU's are parallelization, specifically [instruction-level parallelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism).  Additionally, there's little fundamental distinction between a single GPU and multiple GPU's; either way, it's just a bunch of compute units, just in one case they're wired together on one board versus several boards.  Related:  [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD).

Comment: There is a big  fundamental difference between single a multiple cards at the algorithm strategy level, on how you handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with the relevant implementations, training a neural network means optimizing that neural network's parameters, e.g. the weights of neural connections.

Common optimization methods include [quasi-Newton methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method#Search_for_extrema:_optimization), which are rate-limited by matrix math operations like matrix inversion.  GPU's can greatly improve calculation speed here.

References:

- ["Matrix computations on the GPU"](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/Misc/mygpu.pdf), Nvidia (2013-08), discusses how their GPU's can perform large matrix operations in parallel.
- ["Using GPUs"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu), TensorFlow, talks about how TensorFlow can be configured to use GPU's.